# Why does factor analysis fail when the number of cases is less than the number of variables?

Tags: dataset, sample-size, factor-analysis, matrix

I am trying to run a factor analysis my data composed by 21 cases and 23 variables of continuous data. Ideally, I am trying to extract three factors, but I have also tried with four, five, and six.

However, I get the error message:

> "system is computationally singular"

I assume this is because I do not have enough cases.

#### Questions

- Why does factor analysis fail when the number of cases is less than the number of variables?
- How many cases are needed for factor analysis to be calculated?

Comment: Can you say how many rows & columns you have in your dataset? Are your rows observations & your columns measurements (as is typical)? How many factors are you trying to extract?

Comment: There are different rules of thumbs on this and depends on whether the items are continuous or categorical - a lot of info. online - some as low as five rows per item. But also depends on the number of factors to extract and correlations between items. Also a different extraction methods can produce a solution for singular or near singular matrices, but check stability of solution - through bootstrapping maybe?